# Is it possible to manipulate the normals of the curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Using the curve and object bevel on it, I got the approximate shape of the object i need. But to get exactly the form that I need, I had to convert the curve into a mesh and change the form in edit mode losing the perfection(Purple one, not perfect).

So i decided to remake it with blue curve

The problem/obstacle is that i cant change the normal of the curve so that the second end was aligned with ring

The desired shape is purple, BUT i want to remake it with blue curve by changing the normal of the second end of the blue curve.
I tried to fix it by rotating the bevel object of the curve, but it changes ALL normals of blue curve.
[image: the first end]

[image: the second end]

Comment: What you want to change is the *tilt* of one the curve's control points.  You can do this by selecting a control while in edit and changing the tilt in the sidebar, or by using the "tilt" operation, ctrl t for me.

Comment: @Nathan Thank you.